# At what age are you able to speak Parseltongue?

Tags: harry-potter, languages, parseltongue

Parseltongue is considered an 'inherited magical ability', meaning it is passed down through the bloodline. Does this mean that you are able to speak Parseltongue when you are a 1 month old baby (creepy baby)? Or does the ability to speak to snakes come around the time that you learn to speak a human language?

Comment: At what age can snakes speak parsel?

Comment: @Fabian that depends on how quickly Papa/Mama Snake teaches parsel

Comment: My guess would be  ssssix or sssseven.

Comment: You assume that Parseltongues are English-speakers.

Comment: Thank you, @JustinOhms.  I know that Stack Exchange often doesn't bother to inform you of highly upvoted comments.  So I wanted to let you know that your comment has been appreciated by many people.  (Exceeding 20 up-votes within approximately the first 8 hours.)  Nicely done.

Comment: Yeah, they might *just* speak Snake.

Comment: Me?  I think I was about 5 1/2.

Comment: Thanks @TOOGAM you are right I would not have noticed especially since this was my first post on the scifi exchange.  It's great to know that a little levity is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## It’s not really clear from the information we have.

There’s no example of a very young child just learning to speak English speaking Parseltongue - everyone we see speaking it is already old enough to have already learned English.

Harry (although his ability to speak Parseltongue was not truly *his*) was able to speak Parseltongue by the age of ten.

> “As the snake slid swiftly past him, Harry could have sworn a low, hissing voice said, ‘Brazil, here I come … Thanksss, amigo.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 2 (The Vanishing Glass)*</sup></sub>

Tom Riddle also learned he could speak Parseltongue before he attended Hogwarts, but the actual age he found out he could speak it isn’t clear - though it would be before 11.

> “Riddle nodded. Dumbledore got to his feet and held out his hand again. Taking it, Riddle said, ‘I can speak to snakes. I found out when we’ve been to the country on trips – they find me, they whisper to me. Is that normal for a wizard?’
>
> Harry could tell that he had withheld mention of this strangest power until that moment, determined to impress.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 13 (The Secret Riddle)*</sup></sub>

The Gaunt family (Marvolo, Morfin, and Merope) spoke Parseltongue to each other at home as a sort of second language even when not talking to a snake, though it’s unclear at what age any of them learned it. It’s possible they became capable of speaking both languages at the same time - but it’s also possible that they learned one first, then the other.

> “*“Darling”,’* whispered Morfin in Parseltongue, looking at his sister. *‘“Darling”, he called her. So he wouldn’t have you anyway.’*
>   Merope was so white Harry felt sure she was going to faint.
>
> *‘What’s that?’* said Gaunt sharply, also in Parseltongue, looking from his son to his daughter. *‘What did you say, Morfin?”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 10 (The House of Gaunt)*</sup></sub>

The Gaunts do seem to prefer speaking Parseltongue over English, most likely as a way of keeping what they’re saying hidden from others, and because it’s a mark of their heritage whereas English can be spoken by anyone.

## Since it was an innate skill, it’d be easier to learn than English.

When children first start to talk, they have to learn individual words and their meanings. However, Parseltongue (at least for those who have the innate ability to speak it - rather than learning it like Dumbledore did) seems to be something that is picked up all at once. While Harry is a special case since it’s not his ability, young Tom Riddle also didn’t seem to need to learn individual words to be able to speak Parseltongue, it sounds like he knew it all at once.

However, it may or may not still need a knowledge of a human language first - this is unclear from the information we have.

Comment: When did you learn it?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I learned it bit by bit, since I don’t have the innate ability. ;)

Comment: That's why I follow your teachings. If you want something bad enough, you have to go for it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

***Phillipus Aureolus Theophrastus Bombastus von Hohenheim (Paracelsus)*** is known for the discovery of Parseltongue in 16th Century. Mentioned in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chocolate Frog Cards ([here](https://www.pottermore.com/features/sweets-and-treats-infographic)).

Apart form Harry, the most well-known Parselmouth was Salazar Slytherin himself. Then came Voldemort and even Dumbledore. According to Pottermore [here](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-didnt-know-about-parseltongue),

> As J.K Rowling revealed, ***Albus Dumbledore had mastered Parseltongue too***. – although he could not speak it aloud. We’re not sure why Albus learnt the language, but perhaps the Hogwarts headmaster wanted a better understanding of Voldemort.

Lesser known Parselmouths were the Gaunts (Voldemort's Uncle, Grandfather and mother). As seen in one of the memories in the Pensieve in *The Half Blood Prince*, Morfin and Marvolo Gaunt always conversed in Parseltongue (their English shows that they learnt it very late; English was probably their second language). As Rowling puts it,

> Seeing as the Gaunts were so dedicated to their pure-blood line, it makes sense they would isolate others as much as possible by using their own language.

So indeed being a Parseltongue is quite rare, but it can be learnt as any other language (**Dumbledore proved it!** Yay!). But the important thing is that  ***Parseltongue usually requires the speaker to face a snake-based creature or object shaped like a snake***. However skilled parselmouths like the Gaunts were able to speak at will.

In conclusion, One can speak Parseltongue at any given age. Parseltongue may even be the first language you learn. Very little is known about the Gaunts but, by looking at their fluency, it could be possible that they learnt Parseltongue first and then English.

Comment: How could Paracelsus discover parseltongue in the 16th century if Slytherin was already speaking it in the late 10th century?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question asked. It's just a(n incomplete) list of known speakers.

Comment: Is there evidence that speaking Parseltongue usually requires facing a snake or snake-like thing? We know it helped Harry, but maybe that was just his way of inexpertly tapping into a power he wasn't very practiced at?

Comment: @Shreedhar - So your source for the first paragraph is an image that contains the word "Paracelsus"? I'm not sure how that implies he discovered paresltounge, or even that he had a ridiculously long name. If you actually checked Philosophers Stone you will see that it mentions nothing more than the infographic (i.e. That someone named "Paracelsus" had a chocolate frog card.).

Comment: @Shreedhar - The only sources for the text of the card are video games. And most of the video games don't say any of that about him. There are four variants of his card found among the different video games, and only the least common variant says anything about Parseltounge (it also says some weird nonsense about Leonardo da Vinci). And no licensed HP source gives him that ridiculous name. It seems like you're confusing the fictional character with the historical figure he was based on.

Comment: @Shreedhar - You also might want to switch the quote about Dumbledore to a quote from the actual interview instead of a clickbait article that merely references it. Primary sources are always preferred.

Comment: @Shreedhar - You attribute that second quote to Rowling, but it doesn't seem to be found in any of her written works or interviews. It seems to just be a quote from that clickbait Pottermore article you linked. While Pottermore does host a few of Rowling's writings (found in their "writing by jk rowling" section), the rest of the website isn't, and doesn't claim to be, written by her.

Comment: The last paragraph appears to answer the question by claiming that "One can speak Parseltongue at any given age". I don't see any evidence for that the rest of the post.

Comment: While this post _does try_ to answer the question, the conclusion does not follow from all that came before it. I suggest you pare that down and try to find some evidence for your conclusion.

Comment: In the future when you see information on HP Wikia that you can't find in a an actual source just assume that they made it up. Don't dump it here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72592/discussion-on-answer-by-shreedhar-at-what-age-are-you-able-to-speak-parseltongue).